# How can I submit a form in Yii whenever a textfield changes?

Tags: yii, form-submit, onchange, keyboard-events

I am actually coding a website using Yii framework. I have a view with several tables, each containing a form with a unique id. Each form has a `textfield`, and 2 `dropdownlists`. Each form must be submitted when the `textfield` `onkeyup` event is triggered and when each `dropdownlist` `onchange` event is triggered.

Note that for the `onkeyup` event, you must wait for around 500 ms before submitting the form.

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: http://whyareyoupostingprogrammingrequests.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just write js function.

```
$('input[type=text]').keyup(function(){
   setInterval(function(){
     $(this).closest("form").submit();
      },500);
})

$("select").change(function(){
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
})
```

I suggest you ta have same classes for input[type=text] and for dropdowns. so it will be more easy for select.